# C# type casting in class from own superclass

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting, stack-overflow, boxing

The codes that I write from the source code of a project are below. I got that codes through a decompiler. Program is working good when I install normally but when I compile the source codes, it throws exception below.

Is this possible;

```
public abstract class ComPortSettingsBase
{
}

public class ComportSettings: ComPortSettingsBase
{
}

public abstract class Comport
{
    public ComPortSettingsBase Settings
    {
        get
        {
            return this.settings;
        }
        set
        {
            this.settings = value;
        }
    }
}

public class ComportSetup: Comport
{
    public ComportSettings Settings
    {
        get
        {
           return (ComPortSettings)base.Settings
        }
        set
        {
           // The problem is here.
           // Firts of all type casting is not valid. It causes type casting exception
           // If I remove the type casting it causes stackoverflow exception normally. 

           this.Settings = (ComPortSettingsBase)value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: change `this.Settings = (ComPortSettingsBase)value;` to `base.Settings = value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public class ComportSetup: Comport
{
    public ComportSettings Settings
    {
        get
        {
           return (ComportSettingsBase)base.Settings
        }
        set
        {
           base.Settings = (ComPortSettingsBase)value;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're missing a filed - `private ComportSettingsBase settings;` in the `Comport` class.

less exceptions here:

```
    public abstract class ComPortSettingsBase
{
}

public class ComportSettings : ComPortSettingsBase
{
}

public abstract class Comport
{
    private ComPortSettingsBase settings;
    public ComPortSettingsBase Settings
    {
        get
        {
            return this.settings;
        }
        set
        {
            this.settings = value;
        }
    }
}

public class ComportSetup : Comport
{
    public ComportSettings Settings
    {
        get
        {
            //here the cast is redundant since base.Settings is of type ComPortSettingsBase
            var casted = (ComPortSettingsBase) base.Settings;
            //but this is illegal since you try to return something of type ComPortSettingsBase and tell that it's of type ComportSettings
            return casted;
        }
        set
        {
            //please note that you are casting value to ComPortSettingsBase and this is legal since ComportSettings extends ComPortSettingsBase
            var casted = (ComPortSettingsBase)value;
            //but here you try to assing ComPortSettingsBase to a ComportSettings property, that is illegal
            this.Settings = casted;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry this is my mistake. I updated the question. Class name is 'ComPortSettingsBase'

Answer (score 0):

i think code that was before compile.

```
public abstract class ComPortSettingsBase
{
}

public class ComportSettings : ComPortSettingsBase
{
}

public abstract class Comport
{
    private ComPortSettingsBase settings;
    public ComPortSettingsBase Settings
    {

        get
        {
            return this.settings;
        }
        set
        {
            this.settings = value;
        }
    }
}

public class ComportSetup : Comport
{
    private ComPortSettingsBase Settings;
    public ComportSettings Settings
    {
        get
    {
        return (ComportSettings)base.Settings;
    }
        set
        {
            // The problem is here.
            // Firts of all type casting is not valid. It causes type casting exception
            // If I remove the type casting it causes stackoverflow exception normally. 

            base.Settings = (ComPortSettingsBase)value;
        }
    }
}
```